# Is there a way to disable a nested context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question on how to disable a nested context manager. I have an inside context manager:

```
class cast:

    def __init__(self, enabled: bool = True, dtype) -> None:
        self.prev = False
        self.enabled = enabled
        self.dtype = dtype

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        self.prev = is_cast_enabled()
        set_cast_enabled(self.enabled)
        set_cast_dtype(self.dtype)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type: Any, exc_value: Any, traceback: Any) -> None:
        set_cast_enabled(self.prev)
```

User can call the APIs to cast a region of code to a specific data type,

```
with cast(dtype=numpy.float16):
     c = a + b
```

with this context manager, `self.enabled=True` and the cast is done. For example, here if both a and b are in float32, the output will be float16 since the cast is done.

However, I wanted to a make another context manager, `with no_cast`,
So

```
with no_cast:
    with cast(dtype=numpy.float16):
        c = a + b
```

So that no matter user set the `enabled` to either True or False, the nested context manager won't work.

Is that doable?

I wanted to know how to disable a nested context manager.

Comment: Isn't this just a case where you tell the users "don't do that"?  I suppose you could use a global "prevent_cast" flag, but it seems like a lot of effort for very little return.  On the other hand, the concept of a "hidden cast" seems like a horrific practice.

Comment: How is the context manager making `c = a + b` behave differently? Whatever that's checking, add another flag that `no_cast` sets to disable it.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts what's the "hidden cast" here? Do you have an example? (The case is the cast is from another platform. We can't modify anything. So we are trying to disable it within our context manager.)

Comment: @Barmar We can't modify anything on the `class cast`.

Comment: I wanted to do some hacks to disable the cast context manager.

Comment: What does `set_cast_enabled()` do?

Comment: We need to know how this whole automatic casting thing works, because `no_cast` has to work with that.

Comment: The whole `with cast` concept is setting a condition that changes the behavior of code below.  That's a "hidden cast", and it is horrible engineering.  It should always be clear what `c = a + b` does.

Comment: The `cast` class (apart from being horrible indeed) is broken: It restores the value of the `enabled` flag on exit, but not the value of `dtype`. If that wasn't the case, you could just use a `with cast(False, ...)` context manager. The fact that you can't use `False` as first parameter and elide the second one underlines the fact that this isn't really well-engineered.

Comment: BTW, just to offer another view on why this approach is bad: This conversion setting is global mutable state, which always brings the danger of two parts of the program unintentionally influencing the other. This isn't thread-safe and the code using this won't be reentrant, to add two more aspects here.

Comment: The issue is not that `cast` is good or bad, it's how do we disable it? One trivial way if the above pattern is possible might be to define `no_cast.__enter__` such that it always raises an exception, and just have `no_cast.__exit__` always return `True`. For the record I think the aim of `cast` is Pythonic and I like it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. I wanted to disable this context manager: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/amp/autocast_mode.py#L22

Comment: @willf yes, I wanted to disable the cast context manager. Sorry I was trying to omit other codes to simplify the example.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is the class that I wanted to disable. I simplify the example for questioning here. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/amp/autocast_mode.py#L22

Comment: @willf could you please provide a full example? I didnt get your solution.

Comment: @user3322839 -- I was mistaken by the clarity of the question. What is provided by Barmer seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `no_cast` context manager can redefine `cast` so it doesn't do anything while in this context.

```
class no_cast:
    def __enter__(self):
        global cast
        self.cast = cast
        cast = no_cast.do_nothing
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        global cast
        cast = self.cast
        return True

    def do_nothing(*args):
        pass
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. I wanted to disable this context manager: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/amp/autocast_mode.py#L22

Can we do sth inside the `__exit__` as suggested by @willf set the `set_cast_enabled()` to False while `__enter__` as True?

Comment: That doesn't work because the nested use of `cast` will override it.

Comment: why would your example work here? I don't understand why you put it as global could fix the issue?

Comment: Because it redefines what `cast` does. So when the nested code does `with cast(...):` it calls the `do_nothing` function.

Comment: We have to make it global, otherwise it's just assigning a local variable, and it won't affect the use of `with cast:` in the global scope.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried your methods But I got the error: ```'NoneType' object is not callable```. The autocast becomes None. Do you know why?   https://gist.github.com/mmmeee1111/08d4a41d250bff47d18e48515fb5f512

Comment: do you know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm getting a "too many redirects" error when I click on your link. But I may not have gotten the precise details of writing a context manager right in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the possibility I was thinking of:

```py
import torch

class nocast:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, etype, evalue, etrb):
        return True

with nocast():
    raise Exception
    with torch.autocast("cpu"):
        while n := 0 < 100:
            n += 1
            print(n)
```

Comment: Why do you raise an exception here?