# How to override a context manager correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is a follow-up question of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77418891/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-nested-context-manager).

I was trying to make a new context manager to occasionally turn off an existing context manager. This example redefine a new context manager so that the overrided one doesn't do anything within the new conext manager `no_autocast`. But I hit the error: `'NoneType' object is not callable` when calling the redefined one: `with autocast("cuda", dtype=torch.float16):`. Any idea how to fix it?

```
import torch
from torch import autocast
print(autocast)
class no_autocast():
    def __init__(self):
        self.autocast = None

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global autocast
        self.autocast = autocast
        autocast = no_autocast.do_nothing(*args, **kwargs)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        global autocast
        autocast = self.autocast
   
    def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs):
        pass


with no_autocast():
    print("outer 0:", torch.is_autocast_enabled())
    #torch.set_autocast_enabled(False)
    print("outer 1:", torch.is_autocast_enabled())
    with autocast("cuda", dtype=torch.float16):
        def func(a, b): return a @ b
        print("inner ", torch.is_autocast_enabled())
```

Comment: `__enter__` method should return some value you gonna work with. So in your case it should ends with `return autocast`

Comment: @ArtemStrogin that is actually fine. You only need to return something from `__enter__` if you want to use it like `with no_autocast() as something:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not use global variables for this purpose. With that out of the way, the problem is this line:

```
autocast = no_autocast.do_nothing(*args, **kwargs)
```

You call the `do_nothing` method, which returns `None`. So you set `autocast` to `None`.

You probably mean to do:

```
autocast = no_autocast.do_nothing
```

Which replaces `autocast` with the `do_nothing` method. But you should assign it a context manager, not just a do-nothing method. An example of a simple do-nothing context manager would be

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs):
    yield
```

Comment: can I remove the `global`?

Comment: You can't just remove it, but if your program grows it may be a good idea to not rely on global variables, and to redesign your program so it can avoid setting global variables.